# file reading in python usnig different methods

Tags: python-3.x, file

```
# open file in read mode
f=open(text_file,'r')
# iterate over the file object 
for line in f.read():
    print(line)
# close the file
f.close()
```

the content of file is "Congratulations you have successfully opened the file"! when i try to run this code the output comes in following form:

c (newline) o (newline) n (newline) g.................

...... that is each character is printed individually on a new line because i used read()! but with readline it gives the answer in a single line! why is it so?

Comment: what is the output of just: print(f.read()) gotten from: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

`r.read()` returns one string will all characters (the full file content).

Iterating a string iterates it character wise.

Use

```
for line in f:   # no read()
```

instead to iterate line wise.

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` returns the whole file in a string. `for i in` iterates something. For a string, it iterates over its characters.

For `readline()`, it should not print the line. It would read the first line of the file, then print it character by character, like `read`. Is it possible that you used `readlines()`, which returns the lines as a list.

One more thing: there is `with` which takes a "closable" object and auto-closes it at the end of scope. And you can iterate over a file object. So, your code can be improved like this:

```py
with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        print(i)
```